# Spatial Join for coregistered polygon data from different dates

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, merge, spatial-join, overlay

I have three separate feature datasets of 125 polygons that contain plant respiration, incident sunlight, and soil moisture data collected on three different dates. The polygons are perfectly coregistered/georeferenced; they are simply separate copies of the same dataset. The data should have been entered in one instance of the dataset, with one record per date, but this is what I have to work with.

I want to overlay these datasets and display the mean of the data from the three dates in one record? What tools can be used for this? I have thought of using Merge and then Spatial Join, but it looks to be very time-consuming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your polygon dataset is identical except for the measurements like you stated, you can use one of your files as a main layer and Join all other files to the main one. Once you joined all your files, export the data to save it permenantly. After that you need to Add a field on your attribute table and simply calculate it as "A+B+C" / 3 to have the averages.

Necessary steps for join can be found here: http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Joining_attributes_in_one_table_to_another/005s0000002q000000/

Answer (score 1):

Spatial join offers a simple solution.  You will need to set the merge rule for your respiration, sunlight, and moisture attributes.

Here is a screenshot of the merge rule menu.  Select mean.  If you need more info please let me know.
[image]

Comment: Hello Anil & jbalk, thank you for your responses. I like the join idea, there will likely just be a lot of adding fields - I find **Batch Add Field** only adds your field to the first polygon in the list if it doesn't crash. I prefer a Spatial Join approach as it is more elegant, but I suppose I'll have to do it in many iterations, as I cannot use the tool on more than two datasets at once. Any experience with batching the SJ tool?

Comment: Anil, after setting out a workflow, it became clear that your solution offers the shortest path to the result I want. Thanks!

Comment: Nothing elegant in spatial join approach. Results might vary depending on data quality. Note that in any case attribute joins are much-much faster and more reliable

Comment: You can batch the SJ tool either in a python script or in model builder using an iterator.